# Issue with Displaying Images Based on Language Selection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing an issue in my React application while attempting to display images based on the selected language. Unfortunately, the images are not rendering correctly according to the chosen language.

My code comprises of two main components: ImgData and ImgSwitch. The ImgData component is responsible for handling image loading, while the ImgSwitch component aims to manage the image display based on the language selection.

The problem I'm encountering is that the images are not appearing as expected when utilizing the ImgSwitch component. Although the images are categorized by language and are accurately imported, utilizing ImgSwitch to toggle the images results in a message saying "No image found for the current language."

I have verified the image selection logic within the ImgSwitch component, ensuring the image paths and names are accurate. Additionally, I've reviewed the project's settings such as the package.json file and haven't identified any evident issues.

It's possible that the root cause of this problem lies in either the configuration of my React application or a potential error in the logic utilized for image switching.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to effectively troubleshoot and ultimately resolve this vexing issue.

ImgData.js

```
// Importação das bibliotecas necessárias do React e de componentes relacionados.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ImgSwitch from './imgswitch'; // Importa um componente chamado ImgSwitch de um arquivo chamado 'imgswitch.js'.
import loading from '../img/loading.png'; // Importa uma imagem chamada 'loading.png' do diretório '../img/'.
import { css } from '@emotion/react'; // Importa a função css da biblioteca @emotion/react.
import { RingLoader } from 'react-spinners'; // Importa o componente RingLoader da biblioteca 'react-spinners'.

// Declaração do componente ImgData.
function ImgData() {
  // Definição de estados utilizando o Hook useState do React.
  const [showImage, setShowImage] = useState(false); // Estado para controlar a exibição da imagem.
  const [filesData, setFilesData] = useState([]); // Estado para armazenar os dados dos ficheiros.
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // Estado para controlar o carregamento.

  // Função que é chamada ao clicar no botão para selecionar ficheiros.
  function handleBrowseClick() {
    setIsLoading(true); // Ativa o estado de carregamento.
    const input = document.createElement('input'); // Cria um elemento de input.
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file'); // Define o tipo do input como 'file' (ficheiro).
    input.setAttribute('multiple', ''); // Permite a seleção de múltiplos ficheiros.
    input.addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect); // Adiciona um listener para lidar com a seleção de ficheiros.
    input.click(); // Simula um clique no input de ficheiro.
  }

  // Função chamada quando um ou vários ficheiros são selecionados.
  function handleFileSelect(event) {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files; // Obtém os ficheiros selecionados.

    if (selectedFiles.length > 0) {
      // Cria novos ficheiros com um caminho modificado e os adiciona ao estado.
      const filesWithNewPath = Array.from(selectedFiles).map(file => {
        const fileName = file.name;
        return new File([file], `../img/${fileName}`, { type: file.type });
      });
      setFilesData([...filesData, ...filesWithNewPath]); // Atualiza o estado dos ficheiros.
    }

    setShowImage(true); // Mostra a imagem após selecionar os ficheiros.
  }

  // Estilos para o componente de carregamento.
  const loadingStyle = {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  };

  // Estilos para o spinner.
  const spinnerStyle = css`
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: red;
  `;

  // Renderização do componente ImgData.
  return (
    <div>
      {!showImage && (
        <div style={loadingStyle}>
          {isLoading ? (
            <RingLoader color={'#448b85'} loading={true} css={spinnerStyle} size={50} />
          ) : (
            <img src={loading} alt="Loading" onClick={handleBrowseClick} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
      {showImage && <ImgSwitch filesData={filesData} />}
    </div>
  );
}

// Exportação do componente ImgData para ser utilizado noutras partes da aplicação.
export default ImgData;
```

ImgSwitch.js

```
// Importação das bibliotecas React e Hooks necessários.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Declaração do componente ImgSwitch que recebe props filesData e language.
function ImgSwitch({ filesData, language }) {
  // Estado para controlar a imagem a ser exibida.
  const [displayImage, setDisplayImage] = useState(null);

  // Efeito que é executado quando filesData ou language são alterados.
  useEffect(() => {
    // Procura a imagem traduzida com base no idioma selecionado.
    const translatedImage = filesData.find((fileData) => {
      const { name } = fileData;
      const langPrefix = `${language}-`;

      if (name.startsWith(langPrefix)) {
        console.log('Encontrada imagem com prefixo de idioma atual:', name);
        return true;
      }

      const fallbackLangPrefix = 'EN-';
      if (language !== 'EN' && name.startsWith(fallbackLangPrefix)) {
        console.log('Encontrada imagem com prefixo de idioma alternativo:', name);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });

    console.log('Imagem traduzida:', translatedImage);

    // Define a imagem a ser exibida no estado.
    setDisplayImage(translatedImage);
  }, [filesData, language]);

  // Renderização do componente ImgSwitch.
  return (
    <div>
      {displayImage ? (
        // Exibe a imagem com um URL de objeto criado.
        <img src={URL.createObjectURL(displayImage)} alt={displayImage.name} />
      ) : (
        // Caso não haja imagem para o idioma selecionado.
        <p>Não foi encontrada nenhuma imagem para o idioma atual.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

// Exportação do componente ImgSwitch para ser utilizado noutras partes da aplicação.
export default ImgSwitch;
```

[Browser Upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMwxI.jpg)

What I Tried and Expected:

I attempted to switch images based on the selected language in my React application. I expected the images to display according to the chosen language.

What Actually Resulted:

However, despite organizing the images by language and verifying the logic, the images didn't appear correctly. Instead, the message "No image found for the current language" was displayed.

Steps Taken:

I reviewed the image selection logic in the ImgSwitch component, ensured accurate image paths and names, and checked project settings like package.json. Unfortunately, the issue persisted.

Assistance Needed:

I'm seeking guidance to effectively troubleshoot this issue and achieve the expected behavior.

Thank you for any support or insights provided.